# Question of the Outer measure of a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was given the following problem and I need to check if I approached and solved it correctly

If $A \subseteq R $

$m^{*}(A) = \inf \{ m^*(U) \mid  U  \text{ is open and } A \subseteq U \}$

It is obvious that $m^*(A) \leq   \inf \{  m^*(U) \mid U  \text{ is open and } A \subseteq U \}$ and for the reverse inequality

I considered any collection of bounded open intervals  {$I_k$} such that $ A \subseteq \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k  $ and since $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k  $ is itself an open set

I took as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty l(I_k) $ $\ge$ $m^*(\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k ) \ge   \inf \{ m^*(U) \mid  U  \text{ is open and } A \subseteq U \}$

and the result followed is it correct? and if not please suggest a way to do it Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to show that $m^*(A)=\inf\{m^*(U) : U \text{ open and } A \subseteq U \}$? If yes what is your definition of outer measure?

Comment: Yes the definition of the outer measure was  m∗(A)=inf {$\sum_{k=0}^\infty l(I_k) $| each $I_k $ is an open bounded interval and $ A \subseteq bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k $ }

Comment: What you can prove with what you thought is $$m^\ast(A)+\epsilon \gt \inf\{m^\ast(U) \mid U \text{ open and } A\subseteq U\}$$ for any epsilon, which implies your desired inequality

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $\inf\{m^*(U):\ U \text{ open }, A\subset U\}\leq m^*(A) $ is trivial,  since one is taking the infimum over more sets. The reverse inequality is automatic: if $A\subset U$, then $m^*(A)\leq m^*(U) $ (after proving that the outer measure is monotone).

Answer (score 0):

that is a directly definition of measure and outer measure,every measure is a generalized function!

as you ask:

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty l(I_k) $ $\ge$ $m^*(\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k ) \ge   \inf \{ m^*(U) \mid  U  \text{ is open and } A \subseteq U \}$

the first inequality is based on the Countable and additivity of the generalized function we defined; the second inequality holds,since the outer measure is an induction of the measure $\mu$